# Share PC storage with BlueStacks?

Tags: storage, bluestacks

I am using BlueStacks Beta 1 but its storage capacity is limited. Is there any way that I can share PC storage so that I can install more apps?

**EDIT**: I have **Bluestacks 0.7.5.2700** installed and it does have limited disk space :(

Please find below screenshots to illustrate the problem.

[image: Storage Snapshot]

[image: SD Card]

[image: Internal Storage]

[image: Pop up Menu from Tray]

Comment: How limited? How many apps do you have?

Comment: You have to choose "Install Here" option to install to the PC. Choosing "Install to phone" will obviously push-install the app on the phone. I am not aware of any storage capacity limitations that are built into Blue Stacks App Player. As long as you are installing to the PC there should be no limitation. The only limitation, if any, is the storage capacity of your PC disk drive.